# Struts 2 development with Dreamweaver

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, struts, dreamweaver

Does anyone here use Dreamweaver for Struts development? I've been working on a web application using Eclipse/vi, but want to use Dreamweaver so that I can apply some nice looking Dreamweaver templates. I looked for tutorials on Struts development with Dreamweaver, but couldn't find any, and when I tried to import my page, a lot of stuff was broken, which I guess is expected since a lot of the html is dynamically generated by servlets/jsps.

So, has anyone had any luck with dreamweaver/struts and if so, could you share how you configured it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't dreamweaver template sites, but you can find tonnes of open source HTML/CSS templates on them:

[OSWD](http://www.oswd.org/)

[Open Design](http://www.opendesigns.org/)

As for importing them, this is how I do it:

1. Bring the template files into your project structure.
2. Rename the .html file to whatever front-end language you're using (.jsp, .ftl, etc.).
3. Split the large sections out into imports (header, main menu, footer).
4. Add the code snippet that will be replaced with your page content.
5. Use this template with all your project files and view it running through a browser.  Even though there are some Eclipse browser plugins out there, it's always better to make sure your project actually works in the tools people will be using to view it.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of templates are you trying to use? Just HTML design templates?

If so possibly exporting these from Dreamweaver into something like Eclipse may be your best bet as Eclipse has much more comprehensive code editor support for the Java based environment.